# When returning a collection pointer, how does the client know if it needs to destroy it?

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers, qt5

Say for instance I have the prototype:

```
QList<Foo *> *methodBar(int someParam);
```

This method returns a QList pointer to the client code - how does the client code know if it needs to destroy the returned pointer?

Is there a convention that says if you are given a pointer it's your business to control it's memory? Or vice versa?

My thoughts to solve this are:

**Option 1:**
Document it in the doc block that the client code has to get rid of the QList once it is done with it.

**Option 2**
Change the signature to something like:

```
void methodBar(int someParam, QList<Foo *> &listForOutput);
```

So that the client code creates the list and definitely knows that it should destroy it when it is finished.

**Option 3**
Use some kind of smart pointer, I'm not sure if this works but if I wrapped a `QList*` inside a `QPointer` and returned a copy of the `QPointer` I assume it would shallow copy the internal `QList*` and then when the `QPointer` went out of scope in the client code it would be destroyed along with the `QList*`.

So which of these options (or perhaps something else?) is the most common in the c++ world. If there is no standard way of doing this I'll accept an answer that it is up to personal preference.

Comment: Usually this is handled by a naming convention. For example cocoa (objective c) uses `newXYZ`, `allocXYZ`, `copyXYZ` and `mutableCopyXYZ` to mark it as the caller's responsibility.

Comment: also anything which is returned as `const` is guaranteed to be the object's responsibility, since the caller isn't allowed to free it (without dangerous casting)

Comment: To be honest this has little to do with Qt, I would consider removing the Qt part and making it a more general C++11 question (make the QList a std::vector or something like that). For more references about smart pointers usage patterns, cf. http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/ and http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/ .

Comment: @peppe: Thank you for those links Peppe. I agree that this is a general c++ question and perhaps the Qt elements and tags will create noise. I'm not sure I want to edit it though because the accepted answer has Qt elements also which may disjoint things somewhat. If a moderator thinks it best to change both then I have no problem with that.

Comment: This is exactly the reason to avoid the use of raw pointers and use smart_pointers instead. Poorly defined interfaces.

Comment: Option 4, at least in this case: Don't return the list by pointer but by value. QList is implicitly shared, so copies are cheap. Passing/Returning containers by pointer isn't Qt style and there's almost never a reason to do it.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thank you Frank, that is also quite helpful. I've looked at the copy constructor docs and found the relevant section on implicit sharing in Qt so I'll read into it. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/implicit-sharing.html#implicitly-shared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the caller to know they take responsibility for the pointer, then use this:

```
std::unique_ptr<QList<Foo *>> methodBar(int someParam);
```

Another advantage is that the caller would have to go out of their way to make the memory not be automatically freed.

A `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied, only moved, so passing a `std::unique_ptr` fairly explicitly causes the responsibility of freeing the memory to be moved from the callee to to the caller.

Note that this would also imply that the objects that are pointed to inside the list are not the responsibility of the caller.  If you wanted those objects also to be the responsibility of the caller, you would use:

```
std::unique_ptr<QList<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>> methodBar(int someParam);
```

Comment: Great, so this is kind of like Option 3 but using the std smart pointers instead of the Qt ones. I can now see how the semantics of "unique_ptr" makes it clear the client code is being given the only copy so they should take care of it. Your bit about the `Foo` objects in the collection was also useful, thanks.

Comment: Just to note for storing `unique_ptr` inside a `QList` I think this isn't actually possible since `QList` doesn't support `std::move` semantics. It operates as expected with `std` collections such as `std::deque` though: `std::deque<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`